# How to import a tlb and a namespace in c++ at runtime when some condition meets?

Tags: c++, com, com-interop, visual-c++

Generally we import a tlb file at the starting of the program like

```
#include < stdio.h >
#import " sql.tlb "
```

But i need to import a tlb file when certain condition meets in the middle of the program

how can i do this. to load dll there is `LoadLibrary()` but to load tlb can i use `LoadLibrary()`.

Since  tlb is generated by using .dll?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can load a type library at runtime using [LoadTypeLib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221027.aspx).

```
ITypeLib *ptlib;
LoadTypeLib("sql.tlb", &ptlib);
```

What you do then with `ptlib` is kind of up in the air as you don't really say what you are trying to do with it.

`ptlib` is an object supporting the [ITypeLib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221549.aspx) interface. It has methods which you can call to enumerate and iterate the types in the type library. Normally you use it in combination with the other interfaces like [ITypeInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221696.aspx) and so on.

I found a fuller tutorial style document [here](http://www.geocities.com/cool_ranju/tlibs.html). Also, this [link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912648.aspx) has some more detail, also it shows the header file and link library you need to use.

```
Header                    oaidl.h, oaidl.idl
Library                   oleaut32.lib, uuid.lib
Windows Embedded CE       Windows CE 2.0 and later
Windows Mobile            Windows Mobile Version 5.0 and later
```

Comment: But loading the type library in the middle of progrm is my requirement

Comment: What do you mean by "in the middle of program"? At runtime? Or at compile time? Or in the middle of some file? Please explain more.

Comment: Can i use this in c++ what header file i need to include to use this one.

Comment: @Cute - in the answer above, the part where it says LoadTypeLib, that's called a link. Try clicking it.

Comment: I added more detail on the header files and so on

Comment: What namespace are you talking about? The type library has no concept of a namespace