# how to import a tlb file programmatically in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, typelib

Currently I am using the statement:

```
 #import "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\test.tlb" named_guids
```

But I am getting the folder path programmatically. i.e., `"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727"`

I have to load `test.tlb` from this path which resides in a variable say, `folderpath`. I have to import the tlb programmatically by concatenating `folderpath+test.tlb`. How can I do this?

Comment: That looks very much like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108537/how-to-import-a-tlb-and-a-namespace-in-c-at-runtime-when-some-condition-meets

Comment: And what is the task you want to accomplish at all?

Comment: Why is the tlb of the project that you compiled yourself located inside .NET directory? How did it get there?

Comment: because this is hard coded to remove this hardcoding i am asking this.

Comment: That tlb file i am generated for c# assebly so that i can access the c# functions in c++

Comment: The tlb file will be as well generated by the VS when compiling the assembly - it will be in the bin\Debug or bin\Release folder. You should reference that file from the VC++ project, not copy it to .NET directory.

Comment: But i need to register my com component.while registering com component it wil generates a tlb file...right i am trying to import that tlb for using that com functions....

Comment: Creating the tlb and registering the assembly as a COM server are unrelated. You could just as well use the tlb generated during compilation of assembly and register the component without the /tlb parameter. That way you would not have this question in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the prog ID instead if this helps, for example:

```
#import "progid:Outlook.Application" named_guids
```

This beats using a hard-coded path.

Comment: How can i exactly do this. suppose my c# namespace is TestNm
and interface is ITest class is SqlClass finally myy tlb is Test.tlb
then #import "progid:Test.tlb" is correct...

Comment: #import "Guid:35145a33-e434-49dc-92cf-e056c508525a" named_guids i tried like this. But it shows can not open the lobrary  "Guid:35145a33-e434-49dc-92cf-e056c508525a" no such type of library

Comment: i tried #import "progid:Test.SqlClass" but got errors plz observe
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195353/how-to-import-a-tlb-using-the-progid

Comment: Have you registered the type library?  You won't be able to access it through either a GUID or a progid unless you do that first.

Answer (score 2):

To programmatically load a TLB file (COM type library) at run-time you can utilize [LoadTypeLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56a7f9e1-810b-4a42-aa4d-691f4304f5ef%28VS.85%29).

A TLB that is being imported at compile-time should be copied to a well known and consistent location where it can be found during a bild.  If you're working in a team environment, you will probably want to check the TLB into the your SCM system so everyone is referencing the same version of the TLB file from the same relative location.

Additionally, the path the TLB is located at can be supplied to the compiler as an include directory (same as is used for header files).